# Div gets re-positioned when browser window is resized

Tags: css, html

I have several divs that I set up to be positioned next to each other. However, when I resize the window to be smaller, the 2nd and third div from the left drops below the first one. How do I make it so that instead of dropping underneath the first div, the browser would show she horizontal scroll bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have fixed width set to these divs?

Please post your html code of the divs

Either you need to put a width to the parent container div as suggested by Arun or post your html to let us see

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the parent div to some value.

```
<div style="width: 700px">
  <div>Content1</div>
  <div>Conten2</div>
  <div>Conten3</div>
</div>
```